# ADBMobile trackState vs ADBMobile trackAction

Tags: ios, mobile, adobe-analytics

I have a question about the SDK 4.x of Adobe Analytics for iOs.
How can we track an event during a trackState call?

For example in a login confirmation page I need to track:

Pagename: "Login Page"

eVarX: "logged"

eventX: that counts the login event

Is this the right code that I need to send our developing team:

```
 NSMutableDictionary *contextData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[contextData setObject:@"logged" forKey:@"myapp.login.LoginStatus"];
[ADBMobile trackState:@"Login Page" data:contextData];
[ADBMobile trackAction:@"myapp.Login" data:contextData];
```

Thank a lot

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work fine.

Unlike Adobe's legacy javascript implementation (where you explicitly set variables/events by name), all of the iOS variable mapping is done through the "Manage Variables and Metrics" area within Adobe Mobile services (see https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/mobile/ios/actions.html for details). On that configuration screen, you would assign the `myapp.Login` action to the appropriate event and `myapp.login.LoginStatus` to the appropriate eVar.

Alternatively, you can perform the mapping through Processing Rules if you have access to that feature. Beyond the above functionality, this can give additional flexibility if you want to set a rule-based event based on contextData values.

In terms of simplicity and code readability, I'd recommend the first option.